# Why does text for Macau look smaller than Hong Kong?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-labels

I thought Macau and Hong Kong only differ by size but are both SARs of China. Why does Google Maps make the text "Hong Kong" bigger?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

The font size of a city name is a visual cue that is used by Google Maps to indicate its population. The font sizes of city names everywhere in the world are not fixed as constants by Google Maps, they are variable, but they are always used as visual cues to indicate the cities' populations relative to neighboring cities in a user-friendly way.

The current population of the Hong Kong Special Administrative Region (SAR) of the People's Republic of China is 7,475,170, based on Worldometer elaboration of the latest United Nations data and the current population of Macau SAR is 646,141. 100% of the population of Hong Kong is urban. <sup>[Worldometer](https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/china-hong-kong-sar-population/)</sup>

Comment: That's an interesting answer. But that doesn't explain why Vientiane also looks bigger than Macau. If you click here https://www.google.com/maps/@22.1263875,110.5974844,5.36z .  If would realize that Vientiane's smaller size didn't make it the same as Macau

Comment: The font sizes of city names everywhere in the world are not fixed as constants by Google Maps, they are variable, but they are always used as visual cues to indicate the cities' population relative to neighboring cities.